# trouble installing driver for edimax ew-7833uac on 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.10, realtek-wireless

Please bear with me, because I'm still shaky on a lot of concepts at play here, but the gist of my problem is that i just bought a usb wifi dongle that purports to be plug and play on all kernels post 3.10.

this turns out to be false however and the instructions and drivers included with the device are all written for 16.04. I tried them anyhow with no success, then I looked for others having similar issues, and plenty of folks also had trouble but all those folks are using 16.04,and their solutions didn't work for me. lastly i looked for opensource drivers of the chipset used in the edimax (realtek RTL8814AU) but they all fail. should i just downgrade to 16.04?

Comment: May we please verify your exact device? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command:  `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/968342/dkms-drivers-for-rtl8812au-rtl8814au-network-dongles-fail-to-build-on-17-10-k

Comment: @heynnema Exactly! As soon as he confirms that he actually has an 8814au device, we can dupe him.