# How to resolve errors from makefile for wireless dongle driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless

After running the `install.sh` file for my wireless dongle driver that I downloaded from the D-link website I get these errors and am unsure how to resolve them. Important to note that I do not have internet access on the computer, making it even harder.

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA-180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA-180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1558: recipe for target '_module_/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA-180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA-180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:1350: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
root@nathan-desk:/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA- 180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411# ^C
root@nathan-desk:/home/nathan/Desktop/DWA 180_DRIVER_4.3.2_LINUX/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411#
```

Comment: @steeldriver If that is the case, what can be done?

Comment: Have you tried this [RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/a/991650/178692) ?

Comment: @steeldriver tried it, but encountered a different error

Answer (score 0):

See my question and answer at [dkms drivers for rtl8812au & rtl8814au network dongles fail to build on 17.10 (kernel 4.13)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968342/dkms-drivers-for-rtl8812au-rtl8814au-network-dongles-fail-to-build-on-17-10-k)

Get the newest rtl8812au driver that's compatible with 18.04 at:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.20.git
```