# DKMS Build Issue with Kernel (4.15.0-20-generic)

Tags: wireless, dkms

While following the instructions in this thread [RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues) I run across the following:

```
root@nathan-desk:/usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2# dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-20-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
```

It seems to be an issue with the kernel. What should I do?

Comment: This means that the driver from that post doesn't build for your kernel. You need to find some other driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my question and answer at [dkms drivers for rtl8812au & rtl8814au network dongles fail to build on 17.10 (kernel 4.13)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968342/dkms-drivers-for-rtl8812au-rtl8814au-network-dongles-fail-to-build-on-17-10-k)

Get the newest rtl8812au driver that's compatible with 18.04 at:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.20.git
```